# Qt Unit Test repeats everything twice in Qt Creator's Application Output pane for Qt 4.8 (but not in Qt 5.2.2)

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt4.8, qtestlib

I just noticed that even on a **fresh new project**, Qt Unit Test writes everything twice in the Application Output pane, in different colors - first in magenta, then in black. I assume this is because it writes to both stdout and stderr.

This happens **on Qt 4.8 but not on Qt 5.2.2**. In Qt 5.2.2 only the black text is printed, as it should.

As an example, for a unit test project that contains only this test:

```
void Untitled15Test::testCase1()
{
    QVERIFY2(false, "Failure");
}
```

The output is this (I use a screenshot so the colors show):

[image]

Is there a way to turn off this behavior? Is it a bug in Qt4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching on the Qt Bug Tracker site I found out it is indeed a bug. I found the [bug report mentioning it](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-9559):

> Description If one turns off the "run on terminal" option on Windows,
>   qDebug's output will be printed twice in the application output pane.
>   This is due to qDebug using OutputDebugString and stderr to output
>   it's messages. To solve this we could do one of these items: Display
>   the OutputDebugString stream and stderr in different panes if "run on
>   terminal" is off. Provide a checkbox to hide the OutputDebugString
>   stream in the application output pane. Prevent QDebug from using
>   OutputDebugString and stderr. Maybe using an environment variable that
>   is set by Qt Creator.

I think that this happens because QTestLib uses `CONFIG   += console`
, while at the same time turning off the "Run in terminal" checkbox, thus triggering this bug.